# ERROR: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure()

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm running Celery via Supervisor on my remote Ubuntu server. It's giving me the following error in my `celery.log`:

```
 (env) zorgan@app:~/app$ tail /var/log/supervisor/celery.log
        password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
      File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
        self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
      File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
        % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, 
    but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable 
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

even though I've added the value to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in my `celery.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'draft1.settings')

app = Celery("draft1", broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Here is my config `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app-celery.conf` if you're curious:

```
[program:app-celery]
command=/home/zorgan/app/env/bin/celery worker -A draft1 --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/zorgan/app/draft1

numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

stopasgroup=true

; Set Celery priority higher than default (999)
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first.
priority=1000
```

any idea what the problem is?

edit:

```
__init__.py:

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

#This will make sure the app is always imported when
#Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Comment: Which version of celery are you using?. Could you add `celery.py` and `draft1/__init__.py` full content? What is the output of `celery -A draft1 worker -l info` executed from the project directory?

Comment: The output of that command is the same error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

We have to follow the below code.

> celery.py

```
import django
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'draft1.settings'
django.setup()

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Reference: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html